# Excel - Comparing two variable length columns, removing duplicates from both

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two separate sized lists in an excel sheet - each around 150,000 columns.
I need to find the *unique* values in one of these columns.  From the ~150,000 records, I'd expect maybe ~800 to be different.

I've had a search around and can't find anything.
What to do?

Cheers,
Jamie

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  Do you want the unique values in one column, the unique values in two columns independently (could be overlap between the columns), or the unique values among the two columns (regardless of location in either column)?  After that, how do you define the duplicates and where do you want to remove them from?  Do you actually want to remove duplicates from the existing data or create new lists (and how many?), containing the unique values?

Answer (score 0):

The title and description requests are slightly different.

You can use the method in http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/770-excel-find-unique-values-between-two-columns.html to solve either one.

Since fixer1234 suggested it, I've copied the info here (though skipping a lot of unnecessary steps):

- The quickest way to get all the unique values is to select the whole column or row.
- Then go to Data -> Sort & Filter -> Advanced
- Check the "Unique Records only" box and select where you want the data to be copied to

Comment: Links, especially external ones, can disappear or otherwise be unavailable, in which case your answer wouldn't have much value.  Can you edit your answer to incorporate a synopsis of the link so your answer is self-contained?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this - it has a Group By command that can produce a list of the unique values.

https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Group-rows-in-a-table-e1b9e916-6fcc-40bf-a6e8-ef928240adf1

Your exact requirements are a bit unclear, but Power Query has lots of data manipulation functionality to automate any further tweaks needed.

Comment: So is there any problem that can't be solved with the universal Power Query Add-in? :-)  On questions like this, where the requirement is unclear, use comments to clarify the question and then provide a definitive answer.  This answer basically says that the tool is capable of handling anything and Group By is the likely feature.  However, even going to the link, it isn't obvious how to solve any specific version of the problem.  How about raising this answer to your usual higher quality?  Make it a complete, self-contained answer to something specific after you know what the question is.

Comment: The question is essentially "find unique values". That's what the PQ Group By command does.